# What clears the lock created by select_for_update in Django?

Tags: django

If I do a select_for_update, when/how does that lock get released?  Some example code:

```
for rec_id in list(1,2,3):
    record = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=rec_id)
    # Do several things to this record
    record.save()
```

Is the lock freed after the `save()` or is it freed after the view returns and the entire transaction is complete?  How can I control the granularity of the lock?

The docs don't seem to say:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

Comment: Why hasn't the answer been accepted?

Comment: Because I went to make sure it was right, and by the time I knew it was, this one had slipped off the radar.  Fixed!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The lock is active for the duration of the transaction, which is controlled by you. So you control the granularity of the lock by controlling the granularity of the transaction, using the usual methods: `@transaction.atomic`, `with transaction.atomic()`, `ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True`, etc. See the [transaction documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/).